# flask json response last element

Tags: python, json, flask

Let's say I have json file as in below:

```
{
  "task": [
    {
      "description": "Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol", 
      "done": False, 
      "id": 1, 
      "title": "Buy groceries"
    }, 
    {
      "description": "Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web", 
      "done": False, 
      "id": 2, 
      "title": "Learn Python"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to know how can access the last element in json response. I have tried below code for incrementing, but it didn't work:

```
id': request.json['task'][-1]['id'] + 1
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I want to auto incerement id in the code. I mean no matter what the frontend will return here it must increase each time

Comment: `request.json['task'][-1]['id'] += 1` you mean this?

Comment: yes. but it didn't work

Comment: what you mean by _didn't work_ ? what happens then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increase both `id`s, you can do this:

```
d = {
  "task": [
   {
      "description": "Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol", 
      "done": False, 
      "id": 1, 
      "title": "Buy groceries"
   }, 
   {
    "description": "Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web", 
    "done": False, 
    "id": 2, 
    "title": "Learn Python"
  }
 ]
}
new_d = {"task":[{a:b+1 if a == "id" else b for a, b in i.items()} for i in d['task']]}
```

Output:

```
{'task': [{'id': 2, 'done': False, 'description': 'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol', 'title': 'Buy groceries'}, {'id': 3, 'done': False, 'description': 'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web', 'title': 'Learn Python'}]}
```

If you want to increment the `id` that exists in the last dictionary in the list:

```
d['task'][-1]['id'] += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But the problem is the actual file is quite big it was just example. In my case I have json file and each request must increase id